# mysql getting the minutes

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, time

I'm having troubles to get minute from a string with `MINUTE()` function, it always gives me **0**

```
 $consulta=  sprintf("SELECT CURTIME()");
 echo $horaActual = $wpdb->get_var( $consulta );

 $consulta=sprintf("SELECT HOUR('$horaActual')");

 $horaActual= $wpdb->get_var( $consulta );

 $consulta=sprintf("SELECT MINUTE('$horaActual')");

 $minutosActuales= $wpdb->get_var( $consulta );
```

22:03:41

0

What is the trouble?

**EDIT:**

the trouble was the var $horaActual was asigned again in the second query. So the call in the third query was agaist a $horaActual=22 so thats why dosn't work. Thanks.

Comment: You are doing it very wrong. Combine those two queries into one, no need to have some PHP variables between those. Let Mysql do it all alone.

Comment: is 410 actually the value in your table? That seems .. well.. odd...

Comment: there are 2 call to curtime and 3 curdate so that is why i put in a php variable. Maybe will be better use a mysql variable instance. 41 is the second.

Comment: `SELECT MINUTE("22:03:41");` should work. Echo $consulta to confirm what it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should simplify your SQL by running it in one statement:

```
SELECT MINUTE( CURTIME() )
```

Comment: you can also use: SELECT MINUTE( NOW() )

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not referring to any stored data, why use MySQL for this at all when PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function will do it all for you?

```
echo date('i');
```